# Prepared statement update - performance improvement

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a single oracle prepared statement in my application which will update the status of around   100,000 records in the table at one shot.
For Example:

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET STATUS=SUCCESS' where STATUS='INIT'
```

The above query will update around more than 100,000 records at one shot.
Is there any way to improve performance like setting batch/fetch size on the prepared statement? how do I do it if I am using a prepared statement with the query like above which I will execute only once as I don't set any parameters for doing in batches?

Comment: prepared statements has nothing to do with large data updates. it's merely a way to create a conventional query. so, it's a query have to be your concern, not prepared statement. And SQL can give you some ways to batch, but you didn't even mentioned which SQL you're using.

Comment: The unit lakh is unknown outside of south-asia, you might want to replace it with 100,000 or one hundred thousand.

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize is not to run one query at a time(because System Latency per query is too slow...)

You can use Batch update.

If you are using Spring then use 
[batchUpdate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)

or if you are dealing with JDBC directly then use

```
preparedStatement.addBatch(); 

preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: But my query is a single one.There is no different inputs for the query.How to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the update into multiple pieces may help by breaking the updates into multiple transactions but I would start with your database setup. If updates are taking a long time you may not have your log size set high enough. There could also be disk bottlenecks.